# Структуры данных. Разновидности древовидных структур. b+ tree

Tags: структуры-данных, дерево, data-structures

Появилась потребность в написании древовидной структуры для хранения большого объёма данных и быстрого их поиска. Столкнулся с проблемой поиска источников информации, где данные структуры подробно рассматривались. Слышал про b,b+,b*,interval b+ деревья. конкретно, хотелось бы выяснить какие различия в b+ и interval b+ деревьях, или это просто разные названия одной и той же идеи. Информации про interval b+ tree не так много, она на английском и в ограниченном доступе. Хотелось бы найти книгу или онлайн ресурс со всеми подобными структурами и их описанием. Спасибо!

Comment: Чем Вам КЧ дерево не угадило?

Comment: Разные виды деревьев и подобных структур имеют свои особенности, соответственно применяются под определённые цели. Возможно КЧ дерево и подходит для моей цели, скорость поиска, вставки, удаления соответствует O(log n), что очень хорошо. НО! Проблема ведь заключается в поиске структурированной информации по данной теме. Как говорится - "а можно всех показать?". В любом случае будет полезно для саморазвития.

Comment: Если хочется информации, ищите в кормене, там есть про деревья, может не все, но есть

Comment: Спасибо, попробую поискать. Если не сложно, укажите название книги. Я же правильно понял? Томас Кормен?

Comment: Алгоритмы построение и анализ Т. Кормен